# Prevent overlapping between 2 Experiments in Google Optimize?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

Could you please help me with a rule that can exclude users that have already been exposed to one of other experiments in Google Optimize?

What is the best approach?

I am thinking about using 1st party cookie variable or some other custom variable that would mark the user as "exposed" so that another experiment will not affect him.

In addition I can use "run custom "JavaScript" in Optimize's visual editor that will create such a cookie. Will that solve the problem?

Also I can't understand how to prevent 2 experiments from running simultaneously. So that user who sees experiment A will not see experiment B or C (free version is limited to 3 experiments). Is there any rules or configuration that can help with that?

Answer (score 2):

Just had to tackle this! The approach by @swapnil-jain seemed to work on the surface level, but unfortunately had some issues.

When Optimize evaluates whether or not a new user should be opted in to a list of experiments, it creates the `_gaexp` cookie once for all opt-ins, it doesn't create it then update it between opt-ins.

So it looks for the `_gaexp` cookie, evalutes opt-in for Exp A (`does not contain` `<expBId>`) and opts a user in to Exp A. Then it evalutes opt-in for Exp B (`does not contain` `<expAId>`), and opts a user in to Exp B. Then it creates a cookie reading something like `GAX1.3.<expAId>.<expDate>.<value>.<expBId>.<expDate>.<value>`.

The problem now is that on their second visit, the user **will be excluded** from seeing the variation for either experiment, because they now **fail** the audience targeting conditions. Their cookie now contains both `<expAId>` and `<expBId>`!

I had similar problems trying to target the `_gaexp` cookie with regex, since the cookie is created all at once for both experiments after the opt-in is decided.

My current working solution is to create a custom JavaScript rule called `rand100`. For a first time user, it generates a random number 0-100. If that number is below 50, they are evaluated for Exp A, and a cookie is stored containing the `rand100` value. If equal to or above 50, they are evaluated for Exp B. For returning users, the cookie is retrieved, and the previous value of `rand100` is returned instead of a new one, and so they still meet the targeting conditions for the experiment they've been opted into.

The one cookie is shared between opt-in evaluations, since it runs the custom JavaScript during Exp A eval, and so the cookie is available for Exp B eval. The cookie is set to expire after 90 days, which is the default expiration for Optimize tracking.

I'm running these experiments at 100% traffic, but technically they are only seeing 50% traffic because of `rand100`. Traffic is split 25%/25%/25%/25% between control/v1/control/v1.

Answer (score 1):

When we create any experiment, google creates an experiment id which we can find in the details section. Also when an experiment is triggered for a user, it sets a `_gaexp` cookie which contains that experiment id (apart from other identifiers).

So, if you want to run two mutually exclusive experiments, all you need to do is exclude a user from the experiment if `_gaexp` contains the id of other. Here are the steps:

- In audience targeting, add a rule and choose `First-party cookie`
- Create a variable and set it's value to `_gaexp`
- Choose the `does not contain` option and add other experiment's id in value
- Save

Repeat the same steps for the other experiment

Comment: I am assuming we would also need to add a traffic allocation rule ? 50% on both the experiments in case of 2 experiments and an equal split ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons that I'm still using Google Experiments.  It provides a lot more control with its api.  With that said, you should be able to achieve the result that you're looking for by setting a cookie in the user's browser.  Here is how I see it playing out:

- All experiment cookies have same the same name but differing values to avoid creating multiple cookies.
- Upon a new session, check to see if cookie exists

  - Exists - fire tag to initialize appropriate experiment.
  - Doesn't Exist - determine which experiment bucket to put user in and fire tag to initialize appropriate experiment.

I know that Optimizely has an algorithm to bucket experiment users in a way that each user can be part of multiple experiment but I don't believe that Google Optimize has that sort of functionality yet.

Comment: Thank you! I have managed to set-up experiment using Google Experiments. Have you solved a flickering problem? I am trying to adapt Optimize's page hiding snippet.

Comment: Typically I solve the flicker in one of two ways.

1) Put the test logic on the server side so that front-end variations are controlled at the template level.
2) By default, hide the element using css, then use javascript to modify the element's styling on page load so that it appears as the page loads.  This might mean that your control gets reported to GA as the variant and that the variant is reported as the control, but you just need to keep that in mind when evaluating results.

Comment: Have you tried to adapt Google Optimize's page-hiding snippet?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252440/page-hiding-snippet-for-google-content-experiments

Comment: Sorry, I have not.  Many of my testing use cases are unique enough that it ends up being more work to utilize Optimize's one-size-fits-all approach than it is to put the test together from scratch using custom js.  What is your test trying to accomplish?  That might help to determine the best approach for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time!
I am familiar with statistics behind multivariate experiments and my aim is to find a technical solution for generating A/B/n variants (more than 15). 
Solution must be flexible, lowcost and universal so I can use it with different sites, clients. Factors for experiments could be styles, texts, js animation, different videos, images, positions, etc.
I found Content Experiments to be a perfect fit for now except the issue with flickering effect.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure I understood the 2nd approach. I need to modify the site's code. But sometimes I assume there could be a problem with access to the code.
"then use javascript to modify the element's styling on page load so that it appears as the page loads" So variant 0 will have a code that will change the element to its before-hiding state (control). Right?
function() {}, // Original: Do nothing. This will render the default HTML.
Instead the line above we use something like 
   document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].style.background="blue;
in case blue was a control version.

Comment: My apologies once again.  The second approach assumed that you had access to the site's CSS.  For example, if the button had a style of 'display: none', on page load you would be able to determine which experiment the user fell into, change the color of the button via javascript, and then remove the 'display: none' styling via javascript so that the correct color would appear without any flicker.  How are you including the experiment code when you don't have access to the site's code?  Are you using Google Tag Manager or a similar tool?

Comment: Yes, I am using Google Tag Manager and Custom HTML tag where I paste code from here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side
Currently there is flickering effect on the test site http://cw61966-wordpress-5.tw1.ru/ The site is just for proof of concept.
"Lear more" button's background is a factor. Control is transparent, Variant 1 is Yellow.
It seemed to me that Optimize's Page-hiding snippet would be a universal solution. However, it does not work as expected. Maybe Optimize's solution is not appropriate to Content Experiments.

Comment: Which variation are you seeing the flicker on?  I didn't seem to notice any flicker on either variants.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for your willingness to help once again. Up to now I think I have solved the problem by adding a hiding script in html code. You can see this script in the source code. I will try to use this code in GTM custom html tag later. I hope I found a correct solution and it will not cause any problems with other sites.

Comment: Hi Gustav, glad to hear that you found something that will work.  If you have any issues when adding the script as a GTM tag, you might need to play around with the page view trigger type to see which works best.  Let me know if you run into any other problems!

Comment: Hi Brian, could you advice me please a solution to my problem with GTM custom HTML tag string length limit? My Content Experiment code consists of 179734 characters. So when I try to save it in GTM as custom HTML code I get an error: "The string length must be between 1 and 102400 characters.". What are the options for overcoming this limitation? Thanks

Comment: Hey Gustav, I'm not sure off the top of my head but would recommend asking that as a new question so that others in the community will see it.